# R - Problems with converting UTM coordinates with the rgdal package

Tags: r, coordinates, gis, coordinate-transformation, rgdal

I have been given the task to convert a large set of UTM coordinates (Zone 33) to lat-long (WGS84) coordinates. The positions are supposed to be located near the Norwegian border. I have tried to convert the coordinates in R using the rgdal package

```
#extracting some examples from data set

lat <- c(7790281, 7726438, 7266202, 7259480, 7271802)
long <- c(1053817, 1054025, 451754, 475228, 462235)
df <- data.frame(lat, long)

#converting from UTM33 to WGS84

library(rgdal)
tmp <- data.frame(coords.x = df$lat, coords.y = df$long)
coordinates(tmp) <-c("coords.x","coords.y")
proj4string(tmp) <- CRS("+proj=utm +zone=33 ellps=WGS84") #UTM zone 33
CRS.new <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326") # WGS84
coords <- spTransform(tmp,CRS.new)

#making a dataframe out of coordinates
coords <- data.frame(lat=coords@coords[,1], long=coords@coords[,2])
```

This yields

```
       lat     long
1 69.19936 5.840162
2 68.92219 5.857922
3 66.55129 2.585804
4 66.52160 2.721701
5 66.58242 2.644578
```

However, when transforming the coordinates with an online converting tool (http://www.rcn.montana.edu/resources/converter.aspx) I get the following different results

```
  lat.corr long.corr
1 69.63112  29.37223
2 69.07562  29.00514
3 65.51455  13.95675
4 65.45688  14.46554
5 65.56618  14.18178
```

When plotting both data sets in the same map, one can clearly see that the points converted with rgdal are misplaced.

[Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBQd9.png)

If have tried to understand what the problem is, but after many hours of consideration and research, I was still unable to find it. Some help to find what the problem is would be much obliged!

Edit: it may have something to do with the Easting coordinates crossing the UTM zone borders. Could it be that rgdal has problems coping with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you mixed latitude and longitude in

```r
tmp <- data.frame(coords.x = df$lat, coords.y = df$long)
```

It should be :

```r
tmp <- data.frame(coords.x = df$lon, coords.y = df$lat)
```

And you get :

```r
> (coords <- data.frame(lon=coords@coords[,1], lat=coords@coords[,2]))
   lon     lat
1 29.37172 69.63114
2 29.00472 69.07564
3 13.95675 65.51455
4 14.46554 65.45688
5 14.18178 65.56618
```

Comment: How could I be so blind! Thank you!